# TSql random sets of values across loops

Tags: t-sql, random

I know how to get random numbers in rows inserted into a table with a single select. But how can I do that such that the result of each select in an iteration of a while loop is different from each other?

The code I'm using looks like this. The values I get in each row in a set are different, but the sets of values are the same for every iteration.

```
WHILE some condition is true
  BEGIN    
    DECLARE @GamesRandomlySorted TABLE
    (
      RandomSortId INT,
      GameId INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @GamesRandomlySorted (RandomSortId, GameId)
    SELECT Checksum(NewId()), GameId
    FROM Games

    SELECT * 
    FROM @GamesRandomlySorted
    ORDER BY RandomSortId
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Rand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) instead? According to Microsoft, if you don't specify seed as a parameter, you will get different values each time you run the script.

Also see [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1473-Seeding-SQL-RAND-Method-With-NEWID-For-Per-Row-Random-Values-Thanks-Joshua-Cyr-.htm) - it shows how to combine NewId and Rand.